# php hooks editing variables

Tags: php, hook

I want to have something similar than wordpress uses for Hooks, basically, in some parts of the code, I want to be able to check if a php file exists, and if so, run that code.

I am using Observer pattern to do that for domain events, but this is actually different as I need to access and modify variables in the index file, for example:

index.php:

```
$a = ['a'];

if (file_exists('hook_example.php')) {
    include('hook_example.php'); 
}

print_r($a);
```

hook_example.php

```
$a[] = 'b';
```

The thing is we have the same index.php file in several servers, but the hook might be different, sometimes we are editing more than one variable, etc.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve that?, a pattern or methodology maybe?.

Comment: As in understand hooks they are optional to be called. For server performance I would include every module but then check with [function_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) or [method_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) if something wants to modify this value - for example `hook_a_alter` as the function / method name. Then call that function with $a as parameter and the return value is assigned to $a again. If your code always wants to edit $a then that is less of a hook and more like a normal function call.

Comment: Having a function is not ideal, as I will need many hooks/functions to alter all variables.

Comment: Sure but why do have to potentially alter all variables individually? Having code that assumes which variable names exist outside of its own code is also not ideal and will probably not hold up outside of your own codebase. I know of one popular example: Drupal. See [Drupal hooks API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/10). That's an overview of potential functions. Keep in mind that `hook` is replaced with your own module name to implement a hook. That's a lot of functions. So better choose fewer hooks but more structured data. Sorry for the long comment.